# How to assign the input from two radio buttons to a single field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am new in coding. I have two radio buttons. If a “yes” is selected in either from them a certain field (here kouAP) must be AUTOMATICALLY set to a value (in this case 0.56). The problems are:

1. how to make both radio buttons to set the value to a single field?
2. How to keep the wished value if one of the is “yes” and the other is “no”? No matter of the order of clicking.

My JQuery makes no sense :(

Thanks you

**HTML**

```
<label for="Pre002">ccs</lable>  
<br />
<input type="radio" id="Pre002o" name="css" value="0">
<label for="Pre002o">none</label>
<input type="radio" id="Pre002d" name="css" value="4">
<label for="Pre002d">yes</label>
<br />
<label for="Pre066">mi</lable>  
<br />
<input type="radio" id="Pre066a" name="mi" value="0">
<label for="Pre066a">yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="Pre066b" name="mi" value="1">
<label for="Pre066b">no</label>
<br />
<input id="kouAP" type=“text” name="kouAP" readonly="true" placeholder="kouAP">
<label for="kouAP">at least one yes</label>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('input[type=radio].css; input[type=radio].mi').click(function(e){
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "Pre002d" || $(this).attr("id") == "Pre066a" ){
    $("#kouAP").val(0.5677075);
  }
  else {
    $("#kouAP").val(0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with code.

Just provide the name of the element you listen the click from.

Replace:

```
$('input[type=radio].css; input[type=radio].mi').click(...);
```

With:

```
$('input').click(...);
```

or:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(...);
```

to avoid future errors.

I just advice you to go through the basics again :)

**EDIT**

For the second question, I guess it's just a work around with if..else. Hope it helps.

```
$('input').click(function(e){
  if ($('#Pre002d').is(':checked') || $('#Pre066a').is(':checked')){
    $("#kouAP").val(0.5677075);
  }
    else{
        $("#kouAP").val(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. It solves only the first part of the question.

Comment: Sorry, should've read it properly. I've included my solution hope it helps.

Comment: I have a question - since there are many radio buttons in the original code, can I assign more buttons to this function as if statements?

Comment: yes, I believe. But I am unclear about the purpose. Can you brief me over it?

Comment: So there are like 7 radio buttons all with yes/no option. Each of them assigns a value to a field like “kouAP” in the code above, but there are 7 from those. The question is can I add all this 7 buttons as if...else statements in only one $(input).click function? Thank in advance.

Comment: yeah sure, just check `$('#id_of_radiobuttons').is(':checked')` in the if statement. Add with `||`  ooperator